# Update Excel from SQL source to only update field when not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an asset management script in SQL that searches for all devices showing a certain version of software reported on a device in the last 90 days. These devices are then associated with some resource, which is owned by a location, and the devices are best located via this association.

I am faced with the problem that because they are 'floating' devices, they may not all necessarily be in use at the same time, and their association may be overwritten by a different device used by the same resource (hence the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on related tables). Ultimately, I want to be able to track "last seen location" for these devices in a way that updates if not `NULL`, but does not overwrite non-`NULL` values with `NULL` (so that the table iteratively populates with resource and location details over a period of time).

Now, because not all of my colleagues have access to SQL, but need to know this information, I want to pull the information into an Excel spreadsheet that updates when run. In order to gradually populate this information, I've tried setting up separate conditional columns that only update from `CurrentResourceName` or `CurrentLocationName` if they are not `NULL`, but I can't see any way to set these conditions up without ultimately overwriting any existing information with `NULL`.

The query that this link runs is as follows:

```
SELECT 
      md.DeviceName
    , md.DeviceSerial
    , md.ApplicationVersion
    , md.CreateDate
    , md.UpdateDate
    , res.CurrentResourceName
    , loc.CurrentLocationName

FROM            [MobileDevice]      md
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Resource]          res ON res.ResourceID = md.ResourceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ResourceOwnership] rso ON res.ResourceID = rso.ResourceID AND rso.OwnershipEnd IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Location]          loc ON loc.LocationID = rso.OwningLocationID

WHERE   md.ApplicationVersion LIKE 'SomeVersion'
    AND md.UpdateDate > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 90)

ORDER BY  loc.CurrentLocationName   ASC
        , md.CreateDate             DESC
        , md.UpdateDate             DESC
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to whether this is possible?

Comment: What database are you using? SQL server?

Comment: If it is SQL Server, look into using the [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) to write data to a file. There are quite a few questions on StackOverflow as well that should give  you a good idea of how to use it if you search for BCP.

Comment: Sorry, it is SQL Server, yes. I've added the relevant tag for that. And I'm looking into BCP now, thank you.

Comment: So this query does not show latest values? You cannot simply replace the Excel spreadsheet with this resultset?

Comment: @Parfait - it does show latest values, but in some cases that means `NULL` where there was previously a value. Ideally, what I'm looking to do is update a record only if the new value is  not `NULL`, and keep the previous record otherwise.

Comment: Consider then saving to a table and update from this query (perhaps save in a view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because queries are flash points of data live at the current runtime they do not store previous data to be used as reference point.

Therefore, consider saving an historical table using the `SELECT ... INTO` command once and then update values from a view of latest results. Then always export historical table to Excel.

**Make-Table Query** *(run once)*

```
SELECT 
      md.DeviceName
    , md.DeviceSerial
    , md.ApplicationVersion
    , md.CreateDate
    , md.UpdateDate
    , res.CurrentResourceName
    , loc.CurrentLocationName

INTO myHistoricalTable

FROM            [MobileDevice]      md
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Resource]          res ON res.ResourceID = md.ResourceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ResourceOwnership] rso ON res.ResourceID = rso.ResourceID 
                                       AND rso.OwnershipEnd IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Location]          loc ON loc.LocationID = rso.OwningLocationID

WHERE   md.ApplicationVersion LIKE 'SomeVersion'
    AND md.UpdateDate > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 90)

ORDER BY  loc.CurrentLocationName   ASC
        , md.CreateDate             DESC
        , md.UpdateDate             DESC
```

**Create View** *(run once)*

```
CREATE VIEW myCurrentView  
AS  --<ORIGINAL SELECT QUERY>
```

**Update Query**  *(run regularly joining table and view)*

```
UPDATE t
SET t.CurrentResourceName = CASE WHEN v.CurrentResourceName IS NOT NULL
                                 THEN v.CurrentResourceName
                                 ELSE t.CurrentResourceName
                            END,
    t.CurrentLocationName = CASE WHEN v.CurrentLocationName IS NOT NULL
                                 THEN v.CurrentLocationName
                                 ELSE t.CurrentLocationName
                            END
FROM myHistoricalTable t
JOIN myCurrentView v
  ON t.DeviceName = v.DeviceName
  AND t.DeviceSerial = v.DeviceSerial
  AND t.ApplicationVersion = v.ApplicationVersion
  AND t.CreateDate = t.CreateDate
  AND t.UpdateDate = v.UpdateDate
```

**Export to/Import from Excel** *(run regularly after above update)*

```
SELECT * FROM myHistoricalTable
```